# Query SQL databases

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to make an android application with a database. But I have not much experience. I would like some help to make query to my database.
My table "crisis" is as follows:

```
ID  StartDate             EndDate
1   2014-11-05 19:26:16   2014-11-05 19:26:46
2   2014-11-05 19:33:33   2014-11-05 19:33:43
3   2014-11-05 19:33:53   2014-11-06 19:35:14
4   2014-11-06 19:35:24   2014-11-06 19:35:54
5   2014-10-07 09:12:00   2014-10-07 09:12:34
6   2014-10-07 09:18:08   2014-10-07 09:19:11
7   2014-12-05 08:12:12   2014-12-06 08:13:11
8   2014-12-12 10:12:00   2014-12-12 10:12:26
9   2014-12-13 07:33:22   2014-12-13 07:33:59
```

Now I'd like to know how can I do to have the number of "crisis" a day, a month or even a year. For example the number of daily crisis:

```
Days        NumberOfCrisis
2014-11-05  3
2014-11-06  1
```

I am also having the average duration of attacks per day, week and even year.
Please, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is it sqlite or mysql ???

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I use sqlite database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is just `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` for each group, but before use the group by you need to cast the datetime to:

- date with [`DATE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to get counts for each days.
- `Year` to get yearly count.
- `month` (or monthname) to get monthly counts.
- `WEEK` to get weekly counts.

  ```
  SELECT DATE(startDate) AS Days, COUNT(ID) AS NumberOfCrisis
  FROM crisis
  GROUP BY DATE(startDate);

  ------

  SELECT monthname(startDate) AS Month, COUNT(ID) AS NumberOfCrisis
  FROM crisis
  GROUP BY monthname(startDate);

  -------

  SELECT YEAR(startDate) AS Year, COUNT(ID) AS NumberOfCrisis
  FROM crisis
  GROUP BY YEAR(startDate);

  -------

  SELECT Week(startDate) AS Weeks, COUNT(ID) AS NumberOfCrisis
  FROM crisis
  GROUP BY Week(startDate);
  ```

---

For the average duration for each crisis, you need to get the duration for each crisis first using [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT ID, TIMEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate) AS CrisisDuration
FROM crisis
```

This will give you something like this:

[image]

Then you can use `AVG` to get the average of the duration across all the crisis:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate))) AS AverageCrisisDuration
FROM crisis;
```

This will give you something like:

[image]

The use of [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) after average is to display the seconds from integer to `hh:mm:ss` format.

And to get the average for each month, year, or week, you just need to add a group by:

```
SELECT 
  Monthname(startdate) AS Month, 
  SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate))) AS AverageCrisisDuration
FROM crisis
GROUP BY Monthname(startdate);
```

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just try it works. If I would like to have the average duration of crises?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : you forgot to use AVG ?

Comment: @EricMbatchou - Please see my edit for weekly and yearly counts

Answer (score 0):

use `Group by` with `Count`

```
SELECT COUNT(startDate) From crisis GROUP BY DATE(startDate)

SELECT COUNT(startDate) From crisis GROUP BY MONTH(startDate)

SELECT COUNT(startDate) From crisis GROUP BY YEAR(startDate)

SELECT COUNT(startDate) From crisis GROUP BY WEEK(startDate)

SELECT COUNT(startDate) From crisis GROUP BY YEAR(startDate)
```

For average time difference use :-

```
AVG(timestampdiff(SECOND, startDate, EndDate))
```

Comment: You're missing average duration, and he didn't ask for month (but it's useful for him, I guess...)

Answer (score 0):

If using MySQL as your tag suggests :

Number of crisis per day, week end year :

```
SELECT DATE(startDate) AS Days, COUNT(ID) AS NumberOfCrisis
FROM crisis
GROUP BY DATE(startDate)

SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(startDate) AS Days, COUNT(ID) AS NumberOfCrisis
FROM crisis
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(startDate)

SELECT YEAR(startDate) AS Days, COUNT(ID) AS NumberOfCrisis
FROM crisis
GROUP BY YEAR(startDate)
```

Average duration per day, week end year :

```
SELECT DATE(startDate), SEC_TO_TIME (AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndDate - StartDate))))
FROM crisis
GROUP BY DATE(startDate)

SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(startDate), SEC_TO_TIME (AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndDate - StartDate))))
FROM crisis
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(startDate)

SELECT YEAR(startDate), SEC_TO_TIME (AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndDate - StartDate))))
FROM crisis
GROUP BY YEAR(startDate)
```

Functions used : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: i really doubt OP really means `mysql` as he tags also `android` and `sqlite`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ETC AS(
    SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),startDate,102) AS startDate
     FROM crisis
) SELECT 
    startDate AS Days, 
    COUNT(1) AS NumberOfCrisis
FROM ETC GROUP BY startDate ORDER BY 1 DESC
```